# Unir varias filas en una sola columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Llevo varias horas tratando de solucionar este problema y no soy capaz. No encuentro forma de hacerlo. Necesito generar dos columnas como las de la imagen anexa, pero cada número de las cadenas concatenadas por el punto y coma de la segunda columna deben estar en una fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, la imagen de arriba debería convertirse en esta otra que he calculado en Excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creé esta función con transac, pero no sé si hay una forma más "SQL" de implementar esto sin necesidad de recurrir a bucles.

```
select * from dbo.Farey(10)

create function Farey(@limit int)
returns @tmp table(id int, num int)
as 
begin
    declare @n int =1
    while(@n<@limit)
    begin
        declare @i int = 0
        while(@i<@n+1)
        begin 
            insert into @tmp values(@n,@i)
            set @i=@i+1
        end
        set @n=@n+1
    end
    return 
  end
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Revisa la documentación de [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), puede que te sea útil. Y por favor, comparte el esquema de la tabla en la pregunta para replicarla más fácil.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero me da la sensación de que no has entendido el objetivo que persigo. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: STRING_SPLIT sirve para dividir tus valores separados por ; . A través de esta función podrías crear por ejemplo una tabla temporal con los valores correctos haciendo 2 bucles. 1 para los ID generales y el otro hace una consulta con el ID separando los contenidos. Luego ese lo añades a la tabla temporal y cuando termines haces un SELECT de la tabla temporal y luego le haces un drop

Comment: Conozco perfectamente el funcionamiento de la función STRING_SPLIT, pero quizá me expliqué mal en mi consulta. ¿Habéis visto la función que he publicado de muestra? Pues necesito, si es posible naturalmente, ese mismo resultado pero con SQL(sin bucles ni código de programación ajeno al standart de SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás este código es lo que buscas, primera parte para generar, segunda parte para dividir:

```
declare @src table (n int, i varchar(8000));

insert @src
select cte.value,
    stuff(( select ';' + cast(iv.value as varchar(3))
            from generate_series(0, cte.value) iv
            for xml path('')
          ), 1, 1, '')
from generate_series(1, 8) cte;
select * from @src;

select n as A, Value as B
from @src
    cross apply string_split(i, ';');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7VVIMap4)

Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es generar la función `Farey` que mencionas sería algo así:

```
create function Farey (@limit int)
returns table as
return
    select a.value as A, b.value as B
    from generate_series(1, @limit) a
        cross apply generate_series(0, a.value) b
```

Si no se dispone de `generate_series` (SQL Server 2022+), se puede usar una función aproximada:

```
create function dbo.gen_series(@start int, @stop int)
returns table as
return
    with 
      t10   as (select n from (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    , t1k   as (select 0 as n
                from t10 as a cross join t10 as b cross join t10 as c)
    , t100k as (select -1 + row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as n
                from t1k as a cross join t10 as b cross join t10 as c)
    select top (1 + @stop - @start) n + @start as value from t100k
```

Comment: Hola Xabi, eso es justo lo que necesitaba. No tengo la versión 2022 de SQL Server que me permite utilizar la función generate_series, pero me las he apañado para generar exactamente lo mismo. Muchísimas gracias.