# Eliminar duplicados de una columna y conservar los datos de la otra

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con dos columnas tal y como se aprecia en la imagen anexa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito eliminar los valores duplicados de la columna Decimal y quedarme con los de la columna Fracción resultado del filtrado anterior, el asunto es que si hago un "Select distinct(decimal),fraccion from [tabla] no funciona.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo decides cual se queda? Tus fracciones están escritas al revés.

Comment: Tienes razón Luis, las puse al revés. Considera que donde aparece 2/0 es 0/2. Necesito quitar los duplicados de la columna "Decimal"(marcados en amarillo) y quedarme con los valores de la columna "Fracción" que aparecen en aquellas filas cuyas celdas en la columna "Decimal" no están en amarillo. Las celdas en amarillo son los valores duplicados que necesito eliminar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrupando por los valores únicos:

```
select min([Fracción]) as Fraccion, [Decimal]
from MiTabla
group by [Decimal]
order by 2
```

Un ejemplo con una [pregunta reciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/608161/unir-varias-filas-en-una-sola-columna) podría ser:

```
declare @num tinyint = 5;
with cte as (
    select str(a.value, 3) + '/'
         + str(b.value, 3) as Frac
         , b.value * 1.0 / a.value as Decim
    from generate_series(1, @num) a
        cross apply generate_series(0, a.value) b
)
select replace(min(Frac), ' ', '') as Frac, Decim
from cte
group by Decim
order by 2
```

Recordando que, si no se dispone de SQL Server 2022+, se puede sustituir `generate_series()` por la función aproximada `dbo.gen_series()` de la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/608161/unir-varias-filas-en-una-sola-columna/608179#608179).

Comment: Muy bueno Xabi. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Hola Xabi, he editado tu respuesta para preguntarte un detalle adicional sobre el ordenamiento. Gracias.

Comment: @JoséManuel para detalles adicionales abre una nueva pregunta

Comment: ¿Por qué si están relacionados con la misma consulta?

Comment: @JoséManuel las ediciones de respuestas son para mejorarlas, no para agregar más consultas allí. Si tu pregunta tiene aún relación con la que redactaste, debes editar _tu pregunta_. Si es una pregunta distinta a la planteada aquí, debes [redactar una nueva pregunta](/questions/ask).

Comment: Tenemos una perspectiva diferente de lo que implica la continuidad coherente de una consulta como esta. En fin, no voy a discutir contigo, pero lo que no entiendo es por qué razón se involucra gente en esta consulta que no ha contribuido a nada productivo además de manifestar trivialidades sin sentido.